# Inserting $ into formatted float java

Tags: java, formatting, printf

I'm trying format a float to have a dollar sign in front of the number. Currently I'm trying to get it to print 150 spaces from the left side.

`System.out.printf("%150.2f", orderTotal);`

This is what I'm using but I can't figure out where to put the `$` I guess I could make the entire thing into a String, but I was wondering if there is a way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: `\$` does that work? -- Or wait, you want 150 spaces to the left then print `$ + orderTotal`?

Comment: Anything you put in a format string outside a format specifier will appear just as you put it.  Here `%150.2f` is the format specifier, so anything you put before or after that will appear literally.

Comment: @ajb: Which is a problem, isn’t it, when adding 150 spaces to the left side?

Comment: @Emz The backslash will not work.  This is a format string, not a regex.

Comment: @Emz yeah I want the $ then the orderTotal but all together. Currently I'm using `String orderTotalString = "$" + orderTotal;`
`System.out.printf("%150s", orderTotalString);` This is giving me somewhat desired results
I don't get the 2 decimal point float like I want but it is giving me something similar

Comment: @minitech I don't know, because I'm not sure what the desired output is.  If he wants a floating dollar sign, then a different solution is needed.

Comment: The desired result is `$533.60` but currently I get `$533.6` or I get `$1085.9099`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
System.out.printf("%150s", String.format ("$%.2f", orderTotal));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.printf("%150s$%.2f", "", orderTotal);
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.format` is just the wrong tool for the task.
Check out `DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance` that's what you want to use.

Comment: Please show what pattern you would use for the OP's question

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you what you want:

```
System.out.printf("%150s", "$" + String.format("%.2f", orderTotal));
```

Using `%150s` put you on the right track, I think.  To format your float so that it has two decimal places, but without adding any extra spaces to the left, just leave off the width field in the format specifier.

I'm assuming here that you want the entire field to have a width of 150; that is, if the currency part is `"$101.20"`, then you want to append 143 spaces on the left.  If you actually want 150 spaces regardless of the amount, then Reimeus' answer will work.

Also, consider using `BigDecimal` instead of `float` or `double` when dealing with currency.  The floating-point types can't handle numbers with decimal places exactly.